# installing requests module in python 2.7 windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, request, installation

I am facing issues while installing request module (python 2.7) on windows.

Tried the below steps as per documentation:

**1**

`pip install requests`

error

`'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

**2**

`easy_install requests`

error

`'easy_install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

**3**

`setup.py`

error

```
C:\Location\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe' warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Location\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data' warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Location\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires' warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Can anyone please advise how to install the module on windows , without downloading any new stuff.

Comment: pip and easy_install both require downloads. have you tried looking at setup.py and looking at the commands it takes?

Comment: You have to download _something_. Even if you had `pip` installed, and it did everything for you… it would obviously have to download `requests` to do that. So… what's the _actual_ requirement you're asking for?

Comment: Anyway, you almost certainly want to either (a) get `pip` set up and just use that from now on, or (b) use [Christoph Gohlke's binary packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and hope you never need a package he hasn't built (or a newer version of one he has). I would strongly recommend (a)—you're a programmer, you should know how to use your machine—but (b) works too.

Comment: @abarnert mate all I am asking for is can I install `requests`, without downloading `pip` or `easy_install`

Comment: @misguided: Of course you can. But why is that an issue?

Comment: Well I do not know how to do it . That is what my question is. How do I install `requests` on windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are four options here:

1. [Get `virtualenv` set up.](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#using-virtualenv) Each virtual environment you create will automatically have `pip`.
2. [Get `pip` set up globally.](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#installing-globally)
3. Learn how to install Python packages manually—in most cases it's as simple as download, unzip, `python setup.py install`, but not always.
4. Use [Christoph Gohlke's binary installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score 43):

If you want to install requests directly you can use the "-m" (module) option available to python.

`python.exe -m pip install requests`

You can do this directly in PowerShell, though you may need to use the full python path (eg. `C:\Python27\python.exe`) instead of just `python.exe`.

As mentioned in the comments, if you have added Python to your path you can simply do:

`python -m pip install requests`

Comment: code only answers are usually flagged as "low quality" then deleted.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I added some text explaining the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Since I have python added to my path, I just needed to do: `python -m pip install requests`

Answer (score 6):

On windows 10 run cmd.exe with admin rights
then type :

1) cd \Python27\scripts

2) pip install requests

It should work. My case was with python 2.7

Comment: Python 2.7.9+ and Python 3.4+ ship with PIP, so it very much depends exactly which version of Python 2.7 you were using.

Answer (score -7):

1. Download the source code(zip or rar package).
2. Run the setup.py inside.