# How to add a library in python urllib2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python ver 3.3. I am trying to access the `requests.get()` method. But I am not able to access this because in my

```
import requests
```

It is showing module not found. How can I install this for the code to work properly?

Comment: If you think my answer helped you, please check my answer as the right answer .. This is the Stackoverflow etiquette!

Comment: related: [installing request module in python 2.7 windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18345763/4279)

Answer (score 1):

install it from pypi repository using pip:

```
pip install requests
```

Don't forget to be root or admin!!

Comment: where is the repository located.From wchich path should i run the command??

Comment: The repository is located online, you don't have to do anything, You just run the above command from any path, but you should have `pip` installed, if not, use `easy_install` instead, this way: `easy_install requests`.

Comment: @user3069600, is that what you want?