# Python PIP and InsecurePlatformWarning

Tags: python, ssl, pip, python-requests

I'm trying to install `requests` library for Python (2.6.6 on CentOS6) as

```
sudo pip install requests[security]
```

I'm getting these error messages:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting requests[security]
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

I ensured all system libraries are in place

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel python-devel libffi-devel
```

and all is good there

so I tried

```
sudo pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

and

```
sudo pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org requests
```

and these fail as well.

Due to some old code I need to stick to Python 2.6

Any idea what is going wrong here and how to address it?

**PS**

I have decided to downgrade `pip` and it came up that errors came up with `pip` version 6.1+. Thoughts on that?

Comment: install certifi "pip install certifi"

Comment: @MohitSolanki I'm getting the same error

Comment: Did you mean "sudo pip install requests[security]" instead of "sudo pip install requests[secure]"? If that is the case, this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811949/pip-install-requestssecurity-vs-pip-install-requests-difference/31812342

Comment: @ArmandoPerez Correct, I have fixed in my question.

Comment: The error message has a link to [this page](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings) that tells you to use [this recommendations](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl-py2) to fix it (in particular they say to `pip install urllib3[secure]` or manually install `pyOpenSSL`, `certifi`, `idna` and `cryptography`. Which part of this process did not work for you since you are asking this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as of 2019, quite a few people are still facing this issue, as they cannot upgrade their system Python (and system-supplied openssl) due to various limitations.

If you'd like to fix the `InsecurePlatformWarning .. (Caused by SSLError .. SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version')`, the following solution can help someone using an old Linux distro:

[Unable to install Python packages using pip in Ubuntu Linux: InsecurePlatformWarning, SSLError, tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646558)

> Python 2.6.6 on CentOS6

In your specific case, the last `cryptography` version to officially support Python 2.6 was cryptography-2.1.1, although a newer version might work. 
The first **manylinux1** cryptography package to include its own OpenSSL (1.1.0f) shared lib binding for Linux, regardless of what's on your platform, has appeared in cryptography-2.0 version. The last cryptography that still officially supported Centos 6.4 was version 1.8.2, while newer versions officially supported CentOS 7.x only:  https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files

Note, cryptography versions<2.0 have no `manylinux1` and didn't ship the openssl/ssllib with them, relying on the system-supplied one only (back then, they did so only for other OSes that had/have even bigger SSL problems). While the cryptography-2.0 (manylinux1) is still worth trying, you will probably have to compile the newer openssl version (1.0.1 - 1.1.0) locally on Centos 6.x, before compiling cryptography 1.8.2 to link against it:
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#using-your-own-openssl-on-linux
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#rhel-centos

There is also an option to build your own statically-linked wheels that will work on your own systems:
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#static-wheels

> That said,

if all you needed was just to install the `requests` lib (without solving the notorious SSLError), specifically in Python 2.6.6 on CentOS6, and you are not going to need TLS 1.2 protocol support from `requests`, you could simply use your Centos repo for that:

`$ yum search requests`
`$ sudo yum install python26-requests`

Or, you could get and install `requests` in a similar way as in the [above-mentioned solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646558), from wheels or from tar.gz downloaded from:
https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Note, the latest `requests` on PyPI depends on the following Python packages: 
urllib3, idna, chardet, certifi

Luckily, these four have no other dependencies and can be obtained from PyPI directly, in the same way - the **"Download Files"** section on PyPI:
https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/
https://pypi.org/project/idna/
https://pypi.org/project/chardet/
https://pypi.org/project/certifi/

You could download and try to install their latest versions, or use 'Release History' section to locate older versions, depending on your use-case and system-specific requirements.

Note, many web servers (including PyPI) nowadays require TLS 1.2 support, both in the client and server backend, to establish an HTTPS connection, so if you will need this type of connections, `requests` will not work without fixing the SSLError the way discussed above (or by compiling a newer Python 2.7.9+ against [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/source/) version 1.0.2+ that would have to be compiled as well in that case, **before** compiling new Python, to link `ssl` module with it).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sudo pip install requests

[secure] is not necessary

Comment: Well, I have done that as first attempt to install it then found at the StackOverflow similar issues with answers which are not working for me so I have posted my issue above.

Comment: Ok. Before you did that. Did you run: pip install --upgrade pip. Maybe your pip is to old for the newest version?

Comment: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages` Funny is I have other machine with the `pip` version 1.3.1 and `pip install` works there

Comment: Have a look at [stackoverflow_link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345890/8868822) .Aktually you can try to install it manually

Comment: You can also try this: python -m pip install requests

Comment: `/usr/bin/python: pip is a package and cannot be directly executed`

Comment: I have decided to try to downgrade `pip` to some version which is going to work

Comment: Ok, or you upgrade python to 3.7.